# Размещение названий выбранных ListBoxItem-ов в string[]

Tags: c#, массивы, wpf, строки

Как поместить названия выбранных элементов `ListBox`-а в строковой массив?

Comment: Может быть вы имеете в виду поместить, а не пометить?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, действительно, опечатка) Спасибо, что не прошли мимо)

Comment: А откуда в ListBox элементы? Вы их "руками" добавляете (`ListBox.Items.Add`) или делаете это через `Binding`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Выбранные элементы ListBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19123305/how-to-get-multiple-selected-items-in-listbox-wpf)
В общем случае:

```
'ListBox_name'.SelectedItems.Cast<'Model_name'>().Select(x => x.'propertyName');
```

Например:

```
SomeListBox.SelectedItems.Cast<MyModel>().Select(x => x.Name);
```

Если Вы используете MVVM с соответствующим биндингом ListBox.ItemsSource, то нужно в классе модели описать свойство IsSelected , сделать [Биндинг](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11142976/how-to-support-listbox-selecteditems-binding-with-mvvm-in-a-navigable-applicatio) далее во ViewModel выполнить:

```
ListOfItems.Where(x => x.IsSelected).Select(x => x.Name);
```

Comment: Судя по всему, нужны ещё скобки после `Cast<>`?

Comment: @VladD вы правы. Исправил. Странно, что никто раньше не обратил на это внимание